# Need the updated parameters for push_transaction

Tags: transactions, transfer

I have some problems trying to transfer EOS in `push_transaction`. I followed the instructions from https://steemit.com/eos/@noprom/using-eos-rpc-api-to-transfer-eos and other references because the documentation was outdated.

Here is the detail for my `push_transaction` :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/push_transaction

{  
   "compression":"none",
   "signatures":[  
      "SIG_K1_Ki1Q8SAiZnBWhjkMQM5gmaBhigGrFdVvgrKfpSue75NbR6Er2hinxWapbbE94YCnyPRcqUZizjjFao1oNyHGJUYFR4MeEF"
   ],
   "transaction":{  
      "actions":{  
         "account":"idxtester121",
         "name":"transfer",
         "authorization":{  
            "actor":"idxtester121",
            "permission":"active"
         },
         "data":"1044b82a63957b729015d266a9c8a67ef04902000000000004454f5300000000087465737473656e64"
      },
      "delay_sec":0,
      "expiration":"2019-01-16T07:31:47",
      "max_kcpu_usage":0,
      "max_net_usage_words":0,
      "ref_block_num":21690,
      "ref_block_prefix":2522481250,
      "region":0
   }
}
```

Below is the response :

```
object(stdClass)#31 (3) {
  ["code"]=>
  int(500)
  ["message"]=>
  string(22) "Internal Service Error"
  ["error"]=>
  object(stdClass)#32 (4) {
    ["code"]=>
    int(3010010)
    ["name"]=>
    string(33) "packed_transaction_type_exception"
    ["what"]=>
    string(26) "Invalid packed transaction"
    ["details"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#33 (4) {
        ["message"]=>
        string(26) "Invalid packed transaction"
        ["file"]=>
        string(16) "chain_plugin.cpp"
        ["line_number"]=>
        int(1560)
        ["method"]=>
        string(16) "push_transaction"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#34 (4) {
        ["message"]=>
        string(38) "Invalid cast from object_type to Array"
        ["file"]=>
        string(11) "variant.cpp"
        ["line_number"]=>
        int(545)
        ["method"]=>
        string(9) "get_array"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#35 (4) {
        ["message"]=>
        string(29) "Failed to deserialize variant"
        ["file"]=>
        string(18) "abi_serializer.hpp"
        ["line_number"]=>
        int(689)
        ["method"]=>
        string(12) "from_variant"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From the error response, I think I missed some parameters. What are the updated parameters for `push_transaction`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the data format is incorrect to unserialize.

You can use **cleos --return-packed or -j** to get the packed or jason result.

eg:

> $ cleos -u http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80 transfer -d -j eostemptest1 eostest11111 "1.0 EOS"

```
{
  "expiration": "2019-01-16T11:21:13",
  "ref_block_num": 47231,
  "ref_block_prefix": 1376288694,
  "max_net_usage_words": 0,
  "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
  "delay_sec": 0,
  "context_free_actions": [],
  "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
          "actor": "eostemptest1",
          "permission": "active"
        }
      ],
      "data": "103256b94a9531551042082163953155102700000000000004454f530000000000"
    }
  ],
  "transaction_extensions": [],
  "signatures": [
    "SIG_K1_KhjtLbSsQoVHBXG4BM7MWEkXtDvKmjVZqH5EBszcKdWZmMVkXDpbST2CSds5BQJtKk7orLfapFU5rwED4F3RCah8s1jjML"
  ],
  "context_free_data": []
}
```

> $ cleos -u http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80 transfer -d --return-packed eostemptest1 eostest11111 "1.0 EOS"

```
{
  "signatures": [
    "SIG_K1_KdUUch7YDKeF37Gpioi5ZBQEECmcaBzUvDv7TNCDV5xmqHZte9UYZnF5hbyMA7UjobNcN5zdC8EQ1yZXrybsGfx3JN9zsz"
  ],
  "compression": "none",
  "packed_context_free_data": "",
  "packed_trx": "b8133f5c97b8ef8d42ab000000000100a6823403ea3055000000572d3ccdcd01103256b94a95315500000000a8ed323221103256b94a9531551042082163953155102700000000000004454f53000000000000"
}
```